# Selecting rows, create separate datasets according to rows

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have a dataset that looks like this.

```
# A tibble: 6 x 39
  AssignmentId WorkerId Input.image_url Answer.action1.… Answer.action2.… Answer.comments Answer.gaze1.ga… Answer.gaze2.ga…
  <chr>        <chr>    <chr>                      <int>            <int>           <int>            <int>            <int>
1 30MVJZJNHNI… AW13W4W… 450.png                        0                0              NA                0                0
2 3BDCF01OGYZ… A253S5S… 450.png                        0                1              NA                1                0
3 3U0SRXB7CEA… A3GIXRS… 450.png                        1                1              NA                1                0
4 3D4CH1LGEBY… A1SK0GV… 1141.png                       1                0              NA                1                0
5 3MTMREQS4WN… AK0R311… 1141.png                       1                0               0                0                1
6 3WMOAN2SRC2… A11FQTH… 1141.png                       1                0              NA                0                0
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is grab rows according to the `Input.image.url` variable and create separate datasets. Select first rows of each unique `Input.image.url` variable and combining them. So there will be three datasets with rows like these.

```
> head(first_half_2)
# A tibble: 6 x 39
  AssignmentId WorkerId Input.image_url Answer.action1.… Answer.action2.… Answer.comments Answer.gaze1.ga… Answer.gaze2.ga…
  <chr>        <chr>    <chr>                      <int>            <int>           <int>            <int>            <int>
1 3UOUJI6MTEJ… A1OYE3D… 450.png                        1                0              NA                1                0
2 3OVHNO1VE76… ALWYZOT… 1141.png                       0                1             114                0                1
3 3WI0P0II62X… A2BSMM8… 1039.png                       0                1              25                1                0
4 3UXUOQ9OKF2… A1RK4PG… 1067.png                       0                0              NA                0                0
5 3JPSL1DZ5T4… A1RK4PG… 111.png                        0                0              NA                0                0
6 35LDD5557B9… A253S5S… 1141.png                       1                0              NA                1                0
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be we need to create a sequence column by 'Input.image_url' and `split` based on it to a `list` of `data.frame`s

```
grp <- with(first_half_2, ave(seq_along(Input.image_url), 
      Input.image_url, FUN = seq_along))
lst1 <- split(first_half_2, grp)
```

---

Or more compactly with `rowid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
split(first_half_2, rowid(first_half_2$Input.image_url))
```

Comment: This worked perfect. I used more compact solution using ```data.table``` ! Thanks!!